# Show that $\langle y_i, y_j\rangle = 0 \forall i \neq j.$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $y_1, y_2, . . .$ be a sequence in a Hilbert space.

Let $V_n$ be the linear span
of $\{y_1, y_2, . . . , y_n\}$.

Assume that for $n \ge 1, ∥y_{n+1}∥ \le ∥y − y_{n+1}∥$ for each
$y \in V_n$. Show that $\langle y_i, y_j\rangle  = 0 \forall i \neq j.$oblem

Please give some hints on how to start the problem.I feel totally clueless

Answer (score 1):

W.l.o.g I will assume $\|y_i\|=1$ for any $i$.

By induction, we only have to show that $\langle y_{n+1}, y_i \rangle = 0$ for any $i = 1, \dotsc, n$.

Consider $y = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle y_{n+1},y_i\rangle y_i$ and $z = y_{n+1}-y$. By assumption we have $\| y_{n+1} \|^2 \leq \|z\|^2$.

Computing $\|z\|^2=\langle z,z \rangle$ we get

$$\langle z,z \rangle = \|y_{n+1}\|^2-\sum_{i=1}^n \langle y_{n+1},y_i \rangle^2,$$

hence the inequality can only hold if $\langle y_{n+1},y_i \rangle=0$ for any $1 \leq i \leq n$.

This has the following geometric interpretation:

$\inf_{y \in V_n }\|y-y_{n+1}\|$ is the smallest distance from $y_{n+1}$ to $V_n$. The infimum is well known to be taken on, when $y$ is the orthogonal projection of $v_{n+1}$ on $V_n$, i.e. the assumption of your exercise states that the orthogonal projection of $y_{n+1}$ onto $V_n$ is zero, which means that $v_{n+1}$ is orthogonal to $V_n$.

Comment: I am not getting the induction hypothesis;Can you please explain the induction steps ;

Comment: In induction we first verify for $n=1$ Assume it true for $n=m$ then prove it for $n=m+1$ we did not do that here?

Comment: Please explain if I am wrong